# Issue while fetching data from Aerospike DB Stored in Raw Format

Tags: java, aerospike

Can anyone please suggest how I can retrieve data stored in Raw format in Aerospike using Aerospike client, I'm able to fetch all other sort of data from aerospike, but not the data stored in raw format.
Equivalent functions in C language are present, but not able to found its equivalence in Java. 
C-Language function name for setting data in Aerospike **as_record_set_raw** 
C-Language function name for getting data in Aerospike **as_record_get_bytes**

While fetching data from Java, using Aerospike client, I'm getting *{msg=[B@6d3163a6, length=10}*, while the message is stored in raw format.

Expected Output :- *{msg=66 65 78 44, length=10}* 
**Already checked the encoding part of workspace**

PS :- getBytes() not working, getting following exception :-
*java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long ([B and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')*

`code`

```
        userKey = new Key("test", "testset", key);
        userRecord = client.get(null, userKey);
        if (userRecord != null) {
            System.out.println("\nINFO: User record read successfully! Here are the details:\n");
        System.out.println("msg:   " + userRecord.getValue("msg")+ "\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `getBytes()` method that I can see on the `Record` object, in the recent javadocs at least.

I see the C function `as_set_record_raw()` is documented as `Set specified bin's value to an NULL terminated string`. So I would suggest using the `com.aerospike.client.Record.getString()` java method and use the String `getBytes()` method as needed to get the raw byte array.

Edit: I'm assuming here that you are trying to read back data through the Java client that was written using the C client.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using aerospike client version 5.0.5 which has getBytes() method, Although the problem is solved now, Java client is returning METADATA as well with the original value. So, I skipped first 27 bytes, taking the record in Object. And Yes your assumption is right. I'm doing the same.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the reporting back the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Raw data is literally unencoded bytes stored in the database. For me, the easiest way to work with is to cast the data into a byte array and convert the byte array into a string to use it:

```
userKey = new Key("test", "testset", key);
userRecord = client.get(null, userKey);
if (userRecord != null) {
    byte[] myByteArray = (byte[])userRecord.getValue(msg);
    System.out.println("\nINFO: User record read successfully! Here are the details:\n");
    System.out.println("msg:   " + Arrays.toString(myByteArray) + "\n");
}
```

If you want to see some functioning examples of working with this type of data, in case I borked your code, check out this [code example](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/OperateBit.java) in with the Aerospike Java Client code, and the [java-intro_to_transactions.ipynb](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-dev-notebooks.docker/blob/main/notebooks/java/java-intro_to_transactions.ipynb) notebook in [Aerospike's Tutorial Notebooks](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-dev-notebooks.docker).